# React native Flatlist items with negative margin

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a simple vertical `Flatlist` on Android and I would like to render some of its items with a negative margin. The goal is for those items to appear wider than the Flatlist.

Something like this with red being an item of the flatlist:

[image: Expected result]

Unfortunately, the edges of the items are cut by the edge of the Flatlist.

[image: Current result]

Is there a way to display items that are wider than the Flatlist that renders them?

**EDIT:**
I know I can achieve the visual on my illustration by adding a margin/padding to every item on the list except the red one. What I would like to know is if it is possible to make a specific item wider than the Flatlist itself (not just wider than the other items)

I would rather stylize the one item that needs to be wider, rather than all the others.

Comment: Can you provide some pictures, where we can see how it should look like?

Comment: @Tim I added some illustrations

Answer (score 0):

I myself actually never make an item in FlatList with wider scale of the whole flatList cause I know it's a bad idea and it tends to be ugly looking, just imagine an item with an overlapped verticalScrollIndicator. But the better way is that you can add a View like this.

```
...FlatList tag.....
renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
  return (
    <View style={{ paddingHorizontal:item.isWider ? 0 : '5%' }}>
        ....Children
    </View>
  )
}}
```

You can also write the statement to work only for some particular item index.
By the way, the scroll indicator will not overlap with any item and it has a controlled and better looking UI.

Comment: I edited my question. I would like to have the single red item wider than the Flatlist, instead of stylizing every other items.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to render specific items without margin value, the only thing you have to do is override style.

I create a sample application according to your requirements.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Third Item',
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        title: 'Forth Item',
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        title: 'Fifth Item',
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        title: 'Sixth Item',
    },
];

export default class App extends Component {

    renderItems = ({ item }) => (
        // Suppose if you want to change margin value & background color of id == 3
        <View style={item.id !== 3 ? styles.item : [styles.item, { backgroundColor: 'red', margin: 0 }]}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data={DATA}
                    renderItem={this.renderItems}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    item: {
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        padding: 20,
        marginVertical: 8,
        marginHorizontal: 16,
    },
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: I edited my question. I would like to have the single red item wider than the Flatlist, instead of stylizing every other items.

Answer (score 0):

According to the image you provided, and only style the specific list item, I  could change `align-self`, `width`, and negative `margin` to achieve what you want.

Apply the specific item

```
<FlatList
  contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View style={[styles.item, index === 3 && styles.oversize]} />
  )}
/>
```

styles:

```
oversize: {
  backgroundColor: 'orange',
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  width: 'auto',
  marginHorizontal: -16,
},
```

[Here is working example](https://snack.expo.dev/@chuck_lien/oversize-item)